# how to ‘like’ someone’s participation in (‘going to’) an event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-events

I want to *like* that someone is going to an event.
IIRC, I can do it when I see it in the ‘Ticker’.
It is also possible if someone already *liked* it; that shows up on the wall of the event.
But when I get a notification about the RSVP to my event, it seems that I cannot *like* it.
I can even see it in their ‘Recent Activity’ box but without an option to *like* it.

Am I the victim of some perverted logic, or maybe A/B testing? Or did I just miss something?